# Unable to reference mysqli in PHPStorm, using PHPUnit

Tags: php, mysqli, phpunit, phpstorm

On my Windows 7 machine, with PHP v5.6.7 and MySQL v5.6.23, and using PHPStorm 8, I am attempting to instantiate a mysqli object within a PHPUnit test. When I try, I get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in...
```

If I am running the project as a "Built-in Web Server," it IS able to instantiate mysqli objects. Just not when using PHPUnit. Also, I am able to get other autoloaded classes that that I create in PHPUnit tests. The combination of PHPUnit test and mysqli specifically fails.

Here is regular server code that works:

```
include_once("app/MysqliFactory.php");
use HeloAuth\Sql\MysqliFactory;
$object = MysqliFactory::create();
echo "Success";
```

, and here is the unit test code that does not:

```
namespace HeloAuth\Sql;
include_once("MysqliFactory.php");
use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase;

class MysqliFactoryTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testCreate_shouldReturnValidMysqli()
    {
        $actual = MysqliFactory::create();
    }
}
```

`MysqliFactory` does nothing but create a new mysqli object with the right host, user, etc.

Comment: Please place `phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);` into your test method (e.g. before the line that creates instance of such class) -- so far it sounds like you do not have correct extension loaded. NOTE: you can also use `class_exists()`, `get_declared_classes()` and `extension_loaded()` to see if such class or even whole extension exists/loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `mysqli` being loaded in the CLI? It could be loaded in web requests, but not on the command line.

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, I would check this by using php -i at a command prompt. Is that correct? The output says that mysqli extension is enabled.